# How to delete label generated from loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

So I'm trying to delete labels when a button is clicked, but I get an error on doing so.

This is a loop that generates labels based on the list that I have declared earlier.

```
    t = 150
    i = 0
    for p in products_list:
        self.pr1 = Label(self.right, text=str(products_list[i]), font=('arial 16 bold'), bg='steelblue', fg='white').place(x=0, y=t)
        self.pr2 = Label(self.right, text=(str(quantity_list[i])), font=('arial 16 bold'), bg='steelblue', fg='white').place(x=130, y=t)
        self.pr3 = Label(self.right, text=(str(price_list[i])), font=('arial 16 bold'), bg='steelblue', fg='white').place(x=240, y=t)
        t += 40
        i += 1
```

Now I'm trying to delete those labels when I click a button. I have created a print_bill function which has to delete the labels. I tried:

```
def print_bill(self):
    f = open(str(date), "w+")
    f.write("Bill Bill Bill")
    f.close()

    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Bill", "Bill Generated Successfully")
    self.pr1.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
self.pr1 = Label(...).place(x=0, y=t)
```

What you're basiclly doing in this line, is creating a `Label` object, calling `.place` on that object in-place, and then assigning the result of the method to `self.pr1`. Since `Label.place` returns, `None`, `self.pr1` is assigned to `None`.

You need to call the `.place` method on the label object, *after* assigning it to `self.pr1`. Otherwise, you loose all references to the `Label` object created and it's destroyed.

```
self.pr1 = Label(...)
self.pr1.place(x=0, y=t)
```

In other words, `Label.place` doesn't work in-place. After doing it's work, it returns no references to the object it was called on.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how do I delete the labels generated from that loop. The destroy() method works but deletes  only the last generated label. Is there any way I can delete all the labels?

Comment: You have to call `destory` on each `Label` object, @BibekBhandari.